# How does angular know where ng-include file is located?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm looking at this [sample Angular App](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app).

In the main `html` file called `[index.html][2]`, there is this line:

```
<div ng-include="'header.tpl.html'"></div>
```

However, there is not file `header.tpl.html` in the same directory.

How then does Angular know where to find this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked sample app is built using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), so the file/folder structure of the built application differs from the one you see in the repository.

For example, the templates you are asking about, are collected by [html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js) (Grunt task) and compiled into a single JavaScript file containing code that adds all templates to [`$templateCache`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) (causing them all to be included on app initialization instead of being lazily loaded when required). When the `ng-include` starts looking for files, its first step is looking into the `$templateCache`. Only when it cannot find the template there, it tries to load it from the server (and save it to `$templateCache` for subsequent uses).

See `Gruntfile.js` in the repository for build process details.

Comment: Ah... that explains it. THanks!

Comment: I was waiting to be allowed to do so (gotta wait 10 mins or so)